# Why are dynamic and object interchangeable parameter types when implementing an interface?

Tags: c#, object, dynamic, compiler-errors

This question is not about the general difference between an `object` and `dynamic`, which has already been answered. The following is in regards to a specific use case.

Suppose I have the following interface:

```
public interface IDoesStuff
{
    void Invoke(dynamic foo1, object foo2);
}
```

And suppose I have the following class implementing `IDoesStuff`:

```
public class DoesStuff1 : IDoesStuff
{
    public void Invoke(dynamic foo1, object foo2)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

This looks normal. However, I can interchange `object` and `dynamic` for the parameters. For example, the following class will **not** generate a compiler error for failure to implement `IDoesStuff`:

```
public class DoesStuff2 : IDoesStuff
{
    public void Invoke(object foo1, dynamic foo2)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

So it seems a class implementing this interface will allow me to **not** enforce that a parameter is an `object` and let me use a `dynamic` instead. And writing one way or the other would generate a compiler error depending on how we use the parameters:

```
public void Invoke(dynamic foo1, object foo2)
{
    foo1.Bark(); // compiles
}

public void Invoke(object foo1, dynamic foo2)
{
    foo1.Bark(); // does not compile
}
```

I find this strange because maybe I **do** want to pass an `object` and expose only the few methods it has.

I could also try to see if I can replace another type with `dynamic`:

```
public interface ISomethingElse
{
    void DoWork(int foo)
}

public class SomethingElse : ISomethingElse
{
    public void DoWork(dynamic foo)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Nope, other types will generate a compiler error for not implementing the interface.

So why are `dynamic` and `object` interchangeable parameter types between an interface and its implementing classes?

Comment: There is not actually a such type as `dynamic` as far as the CLR is concerned; all `dynamic` are really just `object` (see marked duplicate). Beyond that, specifying `dynamic` in an interface makes no sense, because `dynamic` is all about implementation, while interfaces are nothing about implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Marking a parameter as `dynamic` vs `object` is like top-level `const` in C++.  It affects code inside the implementing method, but affects the caller not in the slightest.

Please recognize that `dynamic` is not a type at all.  It is syntactic sugar, asking the compiler to convert all usage to a DLR call.  As such, forcing the parameter type to match would accomplish nothing at all.

You have proposed that "maybe I do want to pass an `object` and expose only the few methods it has".  Impossible!

```
public void DoWork(System.Object foo_param)
{
    dynamic foo = foo_param;
    foo.MethodNotFoundInSystemObject();
    ...
}
```

Because the treatment as dynamic takes place inside the method, and cannot be prevented by changing the spelling of the method signature, there's no reason to actually enforce it or even include it in the signature.

That is, if you use reflection to get a `MethodInfo` corresponding to a method declared with a `dynamic` parameter type, you'll find it really is `typeof(System.Object)`.